# Render to html gives no output

Tags: python, html, os.system, nbconvert

I am using a code to extract specific information from several excel files, I render these outputs into html file with  `os.system('jupyter nbconvert --to html --no-input --no-prompt check.ipynb')` rename it and move it to another folder.
When I run the code cleaning the output before, the rendered html is empty and displaying only the markdown code chunks. If there is already an output and I run the code without cleaning it, the new output is displayed in the notebook but in the rendered html I see only the *old output*. How I can be able to render the notebook with the latest output?

Answer (score 2):

`jupyter nbconvert --to html --no-input --no-prompt check.ipynb` only converts the content of the notebook to html.

I think what you want to do is execute the notebook first and then convert it to html.

```sh
jupyter nbconvert --to notebook --execute check.ipynb
jupyter nbconvert --to html --no-input --no-prompt check.ipynb
```

PS: Instead of calling commands with `os.system`, you can call the the nbconvert [python API](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/execute_api.html#executing-notebooks-using-the-python-api-interface) directly:

```py
with open("check.ipynb") as f:
    raw_notebook = nbformat.read(f, as_version=4)
executed_notebook, resources = ExecutePreprocessor(tiemeout=600, kernal_name="python3").preprocess(raw_notebook)

html_exporter = HTMLExporter()
(body, resources) = html_exporter.from_notebook_node(executed_notebook, resources)
with open("check.html") as f:
    f.write(body)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I wasn't be able to solve it with one script. The whole procedure: I extract from several excel files information and displayed them in pandas table in html format. Then this html should be renamed and move it to another folder so I am not really sure if this can happen in one script.  What I did was to create a new script that will execute and convert to html (I used ```jupyter nbconvert --execute --to html --no-input --no-prompt check.ipynb``` ) the notebook while also will rename and move it to another folder.